# Do we want a custom close reason for questions about art history/appreciation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

It's been established that art history and art appreciation, including "history" of current/living artists, is out of scope for this stack. Instead, we're focused primarily on the *making* of art, the doing.

In recent history (past 6 months or less) we've had a few closures for this reason:

[Who is the person in this artwork?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/who-is-the-person-in-this-artwork)
[Casson's 'Little Island' and Bocklin's 'Island of the Dead'](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/5665/cassons-little-island-and-bocklins-island-of-the-dead)
[Why is this painting with Link from Ocarina of Time funny or ironic?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/why-is-this-painting-with-link-from-ocarina-of-time-funny-or-ironic)

There have been more throughout the stack's history. While this isn't a large number, it's a fairly high percentage of our total close questions.

A perk of adding it as a custom close reason for our stack is that it would help signal to users with the ability to vote to close a reason for closing that's immediately clear. The "off-topic" reason has been used fairly often by users, but to me it's not clear that it's because it's art appreciation/history, nor does it act as a signpost for other users.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a note that in the "off topic" section of "vote to close" now only has art-history and belongs on another SE site options. Shouldn't there be one about "not a tutorial site..." for questions like [this?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/7858/how-to-draw-snub-dodecahedron)

Comment: @rebusB If necessary we could add it, but it's not so prevalent as the others, IMO. It could be useful. You're welcome to create a new question about it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm very much in favor of this. I think having a custom explanation in the yellow "off topic" banner on a question is more noticeable and helpful than an explanatory comment (which may or may not get included when the question is closed).

> Questions about **art history, artwork/artist identification, and art appreciation** are not on-topic for this site; we focus on [questions about making art](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Without this, we can still comment and link to our on-topic help page, but I do like custom close reasons :)

Comment: Seconded, I quickly get very bored of typing out the same comment every time this happens.