# Where can I get advice on identifying an artist or style?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to identify a particular painted art style (like precisionism but with a tendency to use thicker paint daubs (oils?)). I can provide examples and images, but I'm aware this site is not suited for this kind of question (as it may invite discussion).

Having done a fair amount of Googling, I'm still not sure where the best place to have a painted art style identified would be. I'm hoping this community will be able to point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

--Rev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think we can't help identify a style or technique. We certainly can!

As far as I'm aware, that's certainly within our scope, though you'll have to be very specific and images certainly help a lot!

We even have a [technique-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique-identification) tag, which you used on this question when it was on the main site. Feel free to look at some of the well-received questions on that tag to see what we expect from these questions.

What we do **not** do is allow users to post a piece of artwork and ask "who made this"?

We are not here to tell you who created a piece of artwork because that is art history.... knowing who made a piece of artwork is tangential to understanding the style so that you can emulate or learn more about it yourself.

The important thing to remember is that we are a site for practical art, not art history. If your question is geared towards **making** art, whether that means learning better how to make something, finding the proper terminology so that you can study up on a specific technique, or understanding how to use the tools associated with an art or craft, we're here for that!

Comment: Well that's terrific! I think I'll try my luck here, then, though one of my examples will be digital (though the 'style' should be medium agnostic). Thank you Catija. =) --Rev

Comment: I look forward to them! I'm sure someone will be able to help or at least point you in the right direction. I should probably link it in my answer but do look over [this answer](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/what-guidelines-should-we-set-for-identification-style-questions) for a guide to how to ask a good ID question here!